# Nginx/Pyramid custom SSL port

Tags: nginx, pyramid, gunicorn, lets-encrypt

As a prefix, I have been using the following stack for some time with great success:

NGINX - web proxy
SSL - configured in nginx
Pyramid web application, served by gunicorn

The above combo works great, here is a working configuration.

```
    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen       80;
        server_name portalapi.example.com;
        # Forward all traffic to SSL
        return         301 https://www.portalapi.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen       80;
        server_name www.portalapi.example.com;
        # Forward all traffic to SSL
        return         301 https://www.portalapi.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    #ssl server 
    server {
    listen         443 ssl;
        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/portalapi.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/portalapi.example.com/privkey.pem;
        server_name    www.portalapi.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /usr/local/www/nginx/portalapi;
            allow all;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.16:8005;
            #proxy_intercept_errors on;
            allow   all;

    }

    error_page   404 500 502 503 504  /index.html;
    location = / {
        root   /home/luke/ecom2/dist;
    }

}
```

Now, this is how I serve my public facing apps, it works very well. For all my internal applications, I used to simply direct users to an internal domain example: http://subdomain.company.domain , again this worked well for a long time.

Now in the wake of KRACK attack although we have some very thorough firewall rules to prevent a lot of attacks, I want to force all internal traffic through SSL, and I don't want to use a self signed certificate, I want to use lets encrypt so I can auto-renew certificates which makes administration much easier (and cheaper).

In order to use lets encrypt, I need to have a public facing DNS and server to perform the ACME challenge (for auto renewing). Now again this was a very easy thing to setup in nginx, and the below config works perfectly for serving static content:

What it does is if a user from the internet accesses intranet.example.com it simply shows a forbidden message. However, if a local user tries, they get forwarded to intranet.example.com:8002 and the port 8002 is only available locally, so there is no way external users can access a webpage on this site

```
geo $local_user {
    192.168.155.0/24 0;
    172.16.10.0/28 1;
    172.16.155.0/24 1;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  intranet.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    # Space for lets encrypt to perform challenges
    location ~ /\.well-known/ {
            root /usr/local/www/nginx/intranet;
    }

    if ($local_user) {
        # If user is local, redirect them to SSL proxy only available locally
        return         301 https://intranet.example.com:8002$request_uri;
    }

# Default block all non local users see
location / {
        root   /home/luke/forbidden_html;
        index  index.html;
}


# This server block is only available to local users inside geo $local_user
# this block listens on an internal port only, so it is never availble to 
# external networks
server {
        listen       8002 default ssl; # listen on a port only accessible locally
        server_name  intranet.example.com;
        ssl_certificate    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.example.com/privkey.pem;

        client_max_body_size 4M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        location / {
        allow   192.168.155.0/24; 
        allow   172.16.10.0/28;   # also add in allow/deny rules in this block (extra security)
        allow   172.16.155.0/24;  

        root   /home/luke/ecom2/dist;
        index  index.html;


    deny   all;
        }


}
```

Now, here comes the pyramid/nginx marrying problem, if I use the same above configuration, but have the below settings for my server on 8002:

```
server {
    listen       8002 default ssl; # listen on a port only accessible locally
    server_name  intranet.example.com;
    ssl_certificate    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/intranet.example.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    location / {
    allow   192.168.155.0/24; 
    allow   172.16.10.0/28;   # also add in allow/deny rules in this block (extra security)
    allow   172.16.155.0/24;  
    # Forward all requests to python application server
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass   http://10.1.1.16:6543;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    deny   all;
    }
```

}

I run into all sorts of problems, first off inside pyramid I was using the following code in my views/templates

```
request.route_url # get route url for desired function
```

Now using request.route_url with the above settings should cause  https://intranet.example.com:8002/login to route tohttps://intranet.example.com:8002/welcome but in reality, this setup would forward a user to: http://intranet.example.com/welcome Again this is not correct.

And if I use route_url with the NGINX proxy setting:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

I get the error: NGINX to return a 400 error:

```
400: The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

And a request to: https://intranet.example.com:8002/ gets reverted to: http://intranet.example.com/login (omitting port and https)

Then I used the same nginx settings (header $htto), but thought I would change to using:

```
request.route_path
```

My theory was this should force everything to stay on the same url prefix, and just forward a user from https://intranet.example.com:8002/login to https://intranet.example.com:8002/welcome but in reality, this setup performed the same way as using route_url.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

I then get an error when navigating to https://intranet.example.com:8002

```
400: The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

And a request to: https://intranet.example.com:8002/ gets reverted to: http://intranet.example.com/login (omitting port and https)

Can anyone assist with the correct setup in order for me to serve my application on https://intranet.example.com:8002

EDIT:

Have also tried:

```
    location / {
        allow   192.168.155.0/24;
        allow   172.16.10.0/28;   # also add in allow/deny rules in this block (extra security)
        allow   172.16.155.0/24;
        # Forward all requests to python application server
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_pass   http://10.1.1.16:8002;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # root   /home/luke/ecom2/dist;
        # index  index.html;


        deny   all;
        }
```

Which gives the same result.

Comment: The solution that was recommended in IRC was to use `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`.

Comment: Yes, this didn't work either. Removing proxy_set_header solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is, obviously, the missing port within the `Location` directives that your backend produces.

Now, why is the port missing?  Most certainly, because of the following code:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

- Note that [`$host`](http://nginx.org/r/$host) itself does not contain `$server_port`, unlike `$http_host`, so, your backend would have no way of knowing which port you meant if you just use `$host` all by itself.
- Note that [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) default of `default` expects `Location` to correspond with the value from `proxy_pass` in order to do its magic (according to documentation), so, your explicit header setting likely interferes with such logic.

---

As such, from the nginx point of view, I see multiple possible independent solutions:

- remove `proxy_set_header Host`, and let `proxy_redirect` do its magic;
- set `proxy_set_header Host` appropriately, to include the port number, e.g., using `$host:$server_port` or `$http_host` as you see fit (if that doesn't work, then perhaps the deficiency is actually within your upstream app itself, but fear not -- read below);
- provide a custom `proxy_redirect` setting, e.g., `proxy_redirect https://pyramid.lan/ /` (equivalent to `proxy_redirect https://pyramid.lan/ https://pyramid.lan:8002/`), which will ensure that all the `Location` responses will have the proper port; the only way this wouldn't work is if your upstream does non-HTTP redirects with the missing port.

Comment: Ok, so this was as simple as removing proxy_set_header, thank you so much. I knew I was close!

Answer (score 2):

I’ve checked a similar configuration and your last example seems correct,
at least for a simplistic gunicorn/pyramid app combination.

Seems something is missing in your puzzle )

Here’s my code (I’m new to `Pyramid` so something might be done better)

#### helloworld.py

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.renderers import render_to_response


def main(request):
    return render_to_response('templates:test.pt', {}, request=request)


with Configurator() as config:
    config.add_route('main', '/')
    config.add_view(main, route_name='main')
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
```

#### templates/test.pt

```
<html>
<body>
    Route url: ${request.route_url('main')}
</body>
</html>
```

#### My nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name             pyramid.lan;

    location / {
        return              301 https://$server_name:8002$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen                      8002;
    server_name                 pyramid.lan;

    ssl                         on;
    ssl_certificate             /usr/local/etc/nginx/cert/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /usr/local/etc/nginx/cert/server.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5678;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

#### This is how I run gunicorn:

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:5678 helloworld:app
```

And yes, it works:

```
$ curl --insecure https://pyramid.lan:8002/
<html>
<body>
    Route url: https://pyramid.lan:8002/
</body>
</html>

$ curl -D - http://pyramid.lan
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 20:41:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://pyramid.lan:8002/
```

#### Lets figure out what might go wrong in your case

- http 400 usually pops up when you go over **httP** instead of **httpS** to a server awaiting **httpS** requests. If there’s no typo in the post and it indeed occurs when you navigate to https://intranet.example.com:8002 it would be nice to see a `curl` request showing this and a `tcpdump` showing what’s happening. Actually you can easily reproduce it by simply typing `http://intranet.example.com:8002`
- another idea is that you’re doing a redirect from your app and the link gets broken when the redirect occurs. I better description on how the user may navigate from `https://intranet.example.com:8002/login` to `.../welcome` would be helpful
- one more idea is that your app is not that simple and you use some middlewares / customization that makes the default logic work differently and your `X-Forwarded-Proto` header gets ignored - in this case the behavior would be just as you described

Comment: Thanks, I can serve the root URL no problem, e.g. pyramid.lan:8002 its when my pyramid app does a return HTTP_FOUND (route_path) it omits the port and the scheme. Thanks for the help, I will investigate further

Comment: Lets try my example app in your environment (i.e. bring it up on a different hidden location) - if it works, the problem is definitely in your app and we can dig deeper in what might be wrong with it. If not - the problem is in nginx configuration. Is it possible?

Comment: @ffeast, see if this helps https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/issues/1435. If not then let me know

Comment: @TarunLalwani, if gunicorn is used PrefixMiddleware doesn't seem to be needed

Comment: @crooksey, did you use `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` for testing now?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work either, I needed to remove proxy_set_header all together.

Comment: This line saved my life: https://$server_name:8002$request_uri; So I have to run ssl on 8443 port, because not root user is running application.